# Analysing Microsoft Chat Bot Load Test result (Application Insights)

Tags: azure, botframework, performance-testing

Here is the detail on one of the transaction (For most of the transactions the observation is the same). The screenshots below are of an "End-to-End transaction details" found under Application Insights's Performance Option.

The total duration of the transaction is around 29.4 seconds out of ~26 seconds is spent between the Step 1 & 2 marked in the below Timeline & Telemetery screenshots.

**Timeline**
[image]

**Telemetery**

[image]

Could someone help me understand the gap between Step 1 & 2 and how can I reduce this to increase the performance.

As you can also see in the Telemetery screenshot that the custom trace messages are also printed (highlighted in Red) mentioned in the MessagesController.cs

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {

        var telemetry = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
    telemetry.TrackTrace("MessagesController POST",
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Warning,
            new Dictionary<string,string> { {"Activity Id", activity.Id} });

        // check if activity is of type message
        if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            telemetry.TrackTrace("MessagesController Type:Message",
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Warning,
            new Dictionary<string,string> { {"Activity Id", activity.Id} });

            //var reply = activity.CreateReply(String.Empty);
            //reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            //await context.SendResponse(reply);
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
```

Is it that after executing this line -  **await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());** it is putting the message in some queue and then it is picked up by the EchoDialog after sometime?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the load script that I had created. The load script was creating same conversation id for multiple users and hence it was taking time to retrieve the dialog record.